# If $-\Delta + a$ is coercive, then $\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 + a u^2 \ge C \int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2$.

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces

In my functional analysis course, we are studying the first eigen value of the laplacian on $H^1_0 (\Omega)$,
$$-\Delta u + a u = \lambda_1^a(\Omega)u$$
for $a \in C^{0, \eta}(\Omega)$ ($0 < \eta < 1$) and $\lambda_1^a(\Omega)$ obtained from the minimization of the functional
$$I_a(u) = \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 + a u^2$$
with the constraint $\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 = 1$. Then, we said that the operator $-\Delta + a$ on $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is *coercive* iff $\lambda_1^a(\Omega) > 0$.

Thereafter, my teacher said that we clearly have that, in the case where $-\Delta + a$ is coercive,
$$I_a(u) \ge C \int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2 = C\|u\|^2_{H^1_0(\Omega)}.$$
for some $C > 0$. Nevertheless, it doesn't seem so obvious to me, because we clearly have
$$I_a(u) \ge \lambda_1^a(\Omega) \int_\Omega u^2,$$
by the definition of $\lambda_1^a(\Omega)$, but how can we deduce the other inequality from this one ? Any help ?

Comment: Should the original PDE be $$\color{red}{-} \Delta u + au = \lambda_{1}^{a}(\Omega)u$$ ? At first glance, it would seem that $I_{a} \ge C \| u \|_{H_{0}^{1}}^{2}$ because coercivity and the [Rayleigh quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient) imply that $a$ must be non-negative and so $I_{a}$ is the sum of non-negative functions. In saying that, I don't actually understand the notation that describes the space $a$ belongs to. What does the $\eta$ represent in $C^{0, \eta}$? It means $a$ is continuous and ?

Comment: Yes right, there is a minus sign that I forgot, I've edited. Well, in my functionnal analysis course, we minimize $I_a$ under the constraint $\|u\|_2^2 = 1$ and we never did any assumption on the behavior of $a$.. The space $C^{0, \eta}$ is an [Holder space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition).

Answer (score 1):

An integration by parts result
\begin{align}
b(u,v) := \int_{\Omega} (-\Delta u v+auv) &= -\int_{\partial\Omega} (\nabla u \cdot n)v+ \int_{\Omega} (\nabla u \cdot \nabla v+auv) \\
&= \int_{\Omega} (\nabla u \cdot \nabla v+auv)  \quad \forall v \in H^1_0(\Omega).
\end{align}
Then combining the $b: H^1_0(\Omega) \times H^1_0(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R} $ coercivity with an eigenvector $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ results.
$$\int_{\Omega} \lambda^a(\Omega) u^2 =  b(u,u)\geq C\|u\|_{H^1_0(\Omega)}^2$$
The equation above implies that  $\lambda^a(\Omega)\geq 0$. Note if $\lambda^a(\Omega)=0$ implies that $u=0$ but that is a contradiction because $\lambda^a(\Omega)$ is an eigenvalue. Conversely,
suposse that $\lambda^a(\Omega)>0$, let $u_\lambda$ an eigenvector in $H^1(\Omega)$ minimizing $I_a$ under the constrain $\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}=1$ then
\begin{align}
b(u,u)=I_a(u) \geq I_a(u_\lambda) = \lambda^a(\Omega) \|u_\lambda\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}= \lambda^a(\Omega) \quad \forall u \in H^1_0(\Omega).
\end{align}
Now taking $u : = \frac{v}{\|v\|_{H^1_0(\Omega)}} \quad \forall v \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ the coercivity follows.

Comment: Why can we take $u = v/\|v\|_{H^1_0(\Omega)}$ for all $v \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ ? $v$ has to satisfy $\|v/\|v\|_{H^1_0(\Omega)}\|_{L^2(\Omega)} = 1$.